# Storyboard won't update on iPad

Tags: uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I'm updating my app to iOS 7 and I encountered problem. Changes made on iPad storyboard don't affect layout in iPad. I tried:

- clean
- deleting derived data
- removing and adding storyboard again

iPhone storyboard works ok. I was also converting project to use Base Internationalization.

What else can I try?